# Ubuntu certificates issue

Tags: ubuntu, curl, certificate, ca

I am trying to use curl and git on my machine with Ubuntu. I was going through a tutorial to set up vim and was encountering an issue with certificates. I ran

```
sudo curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

and I get the following error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

Similarly when I try to run a git clone I get the following error.

```
Cloning into '/home/umar/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

I checked if /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt exists and it does. I am quite new to linux and have a very basic understanding of certificates. What might be causing these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install the ca-certificates package and it fixed the issue.